# Java классы - при создании объекта внутри класса или создании поля над объектом(без new)?

Tags: java

Никак не пойму разницы, есть ли вообще она?  Можно просто объявить поле над объектом внутри класса, а можно создать через new.
Если разница есть, тогда интересно - в случае, когда объявляется поле над объектом, заполняется ли место в heap(мы ведь не использовали new)?

```
`public class Box{
    double radius;
    String color;
    Ball ball = new Ball();
    //Хотя результат получается тот же при создании просто поля над объектом Ball ball;
}`
```

Comment: В чем вопрос? Вы не понимаете назначения полей класса или что?

Comment: Назначение полей понятно. Просто можно поле объявить так Fld fld =new Fld(); А можно вот так Fld fld; В первом случае понятно, что происходит, во втором не понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Ball ball;
```

В данном случае создается переменная объектного типа, но сам объект еще не создан. Память выделяется в стеке.

```
ball = new Ball();
```

Тут уже создается объект Ball и выделяется под него память в куче, а ball является ссылкой на этот объект.

```
Ball ball = new Ball;
```

Более быстрый вариант. Сразу создали объект.

Память под ссылку выделяется в стеке, а под объект в куче

Comment: "Память под ссылку выделяется в стеке, а под объект в куче" - очень плохо.

Comment: Т.е. new это в куче, а без new это в стеке. В стеке работает быстрее. Что плохого?  Где new - это ссылка на кучу.

Comment: @Igor но ведь так и есть, разве нет ? ball является ссылкой на объект и память под него выделяется в стеке, а под созданный Ball память выделяется в куче. Или я в чем то ошибаюсь ?

Comment: В вопросе речь шла о полях класса.

Comment: @СаломатинГ.С. нет. Все ссылки попадают в стек и там они будут находится весь свой жизненный цикл. Сами же объекты будут в куче

Comment: ball является полем объекта, а не локальной переменной. Что тогда находится в куче, если по вашему ответу поля объекта - в стеке?

Comment: @СаломатинГ.С. Ни на что. Ссылочные поля классa инициализируются значением `null`.